# Can't use sox to convert batch wav files

Tags: ubuntu, wav, ubuntu-18.04, sox, audio-converter

The following commands I use to convert batch wav files to single file.

```
sox $(find . -iname '*.wav') out.wav
```

Or

```
sox -m $(cat ../namewav.txt) output.wav
```

here *namewav.txt* is the list of all wav file names.

These commands used to work for me perfectly. But now sox giving me the following errors

```
sox WARN getopt: option `(' not recognized
sox:      SoX v14.4.2

sox FAIL sox: invalid option
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled sox. But its not working.

Comment: So what [shell](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ChangingShells) are you using?

Comment: Using the Bash shell.

Comment: Could you run `cat ../namewav.txt` separately and show us what you get? Everything depends on the output of that subcommand. Could it be that one of your files has a name that contains a left parenthesis?

Comment: @matt you are right. Thats what causing the issue. Can you please make your comment an answer? Thanks very much!

Comment: If you solved it, feel free to answer your own question!